# jquery validate not working on select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have the following default validator options set where i need to show a red color error mesage if the validation is not working

but below seems to work in `Input` and `textareas`, but not on `select`

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: "",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.attr('title', error.addClass('error').text());
        element.attr('placeholder', error.addClass('error').text());
        element.attr('title', error.text());
       },
       highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).addClass('error').removeClass(validClass).removeClass('valid');
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass).addClass('error');
        $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass).addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).removeClass('error').addClass(validClass).addClass('valid');
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).addClass('valid');
        $(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).addClass('valid');
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
.error {
    color:#F00 !important;border:1px solid red !important;
}
.valid {
    color:#060 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you think you could try to post a working example (with the relevant html)? :)

Comment: How the hell you know he has elements with same ID if he doesn't post the html?

Comment: Yeah I saw it but it doesn't means that he have two elements with same id it is just a way to change the element with this id no matter if is a input or select, its not the best way but it's not what you are thinking

Comment: @kpucha OK, Thank you for clarifying this. I'll delete my comments

Comment: hi, here is the link to the site, click on the submit button and you will see, select not validating `http://tinyurl.com/zl5l34d`

Comment: sems no one knows the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using a component that use a span to show the text, so you are not showing the select, you are showing a span (look it with firebug) you will need to change the span color.

Here is your generated HTML:

```
<div class="selector" id="uniform-vehicleID" style="width: 348px;">
    <span style="width: 331px; -moz-user-select: none;">Select One...</span>
    <select data-msg-required="Choose Vehicle" data-rule-required="true" class="form-control error" id="vehicleID" name="vehicleID" aria-required="true" title="Choose Vehicle" placeholder="Choose Vehicle" aria-invalid="true"> 
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="" value="" style="color: red ! important;">Select One...</option> 
        <option value="1">Luxury Sedan or Towncar</option> <option value="2">Stretch Limousine</option> 
        <option value="3">SUV Limousine</option> <option value="4">Business Class Van</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see your select have the `error` class, but there is a span, and what the user see is that span.

If all your selects use the same component you can get the span changing this:

```
$(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).addClass('valid');
```

With this:

```
$(element.form).find("select[id=" + element.id + "]").parent().find("span").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass).addClass('valid');
```

With the `.parent` you will rise the `<div class="selector"...` and with the `.find("span")` you will get the span that its the real text in the screen.